# SafetyNet unable to get result

Tags: android, safetynet

I am trying to learn how to implement safetynet with the reference of a fellow member in stackover. [SafetyNet: package name always return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258489/safetynet-package-name-always-return-null)

The first section of the code is a complete code of SafetyNetVerifier

```
package com.example.stack;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.safetynet.SafetyNet;
import com.google.android.gms.safetynet.SafetyNetApi;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;


public class SafetyNetVerifier implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private final Random mRandom = new SecureRandom();
    private String mResult;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private FragmentActivity activity;

    public SafetyNetVerifier(FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        sendSafetyNetRequest();
    }

    private byte[] getRequestNonce(String data) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[24];
        mRandom.nextBytes(bytes);
        try {
            byteStream.write(bytes);
            byteStream.write(data.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }

        return byteStream.toByteArray();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                .addApi(SafetyNet.API)
                .enableAutoManage(activity, this)
                .build();
    }

    private void sendSafetyNetRequest() {
        Log.e("hqthao", "Sending SafetyNet API request.");

        String nonceData = "Safety Net Sample: " + System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] nonce = getRequestNonce(nonceData);

        SafetyNet.SafetyNetApi.attest(mGoogleApiClient, nonce)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(SafetyNetApi.AttestationResult result) {
                        Status status = result.getStatus();
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            mResult = result.getJwsResult();
                            Log.e("hqthao", "Success! SafetyNet result:\n" + mResult + "\n");
                            SafetyNetResponse response = parseJsonWebSignature(mResult);
                            Log.e("hqthao", response.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Nullable
    private SafetyNetResponse parseJsonWebSignature(String jwsResult) {
        if (jwsResult == null) {
            return null;
        }
        //the JWT (JSON WEB TOKEN) is just a 3 base64 encoded parts concatenated by a . character
        final String[] jwtParts = jwsResult.split("\\.");

        if (jwtParts.length == 3) {
            //we're only really interested in the body/payload
            String decodedPayload = new String(Base64.decode(jwtParts[1], Base64.DEFAULT));

            return SafetyNetResponse.parse(decodedPayload);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e("hqthao", "Error connecting to Google Play Services." + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
    }

}
```

When i tried to debug, it will always stop at

SafetyNet.SafetyNetApi.attest(mGoogleApiClient, nonce)

May I know why is it so? I look at the Safetynet example provide by google and they will usually pair the API Key with the nonce. How can i change mGoogleApiClient to a API KEY?

```
private void sendSafetyNetRequest() {
        Log.e("hqthao", "Sending SafetyNet API request.");

        String nonceData = "Safety Net Sample: " + System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] nonce = getRequestNonce(nonceData);

        SafetyNet.SafetyNetApi.attest(mGoogleApiClient, nonce)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(SafetyNetApi.AttestationResult result) {
                        Status status = result.getStatus();
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            mResult = result.getJwsResult();
                            Log.e("hqthao", "Success! SafetyNet result:\n" + mResult + "\n");
                            SafetyNetResponse response = parseJsonWebSignature(mResult);
                            Log.e("hqthao", response.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the SafetyNetClient interface to test. The sample code is as follows:

```
SafetyNetClient client = SafetyNet.getClient(getActivity());
Task<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResponse> task = client.attest(nonce, BuildConfig.API_KEY);
```

You can refer to the latest code on GitHub：
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-safetynet/blob/master/client/java/SafetyNetSample/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/safetynetsample/SafetyNetSampleFragment.java

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you will need an instance of SafetyNetClient to execute the attest method and not SafetyNetApi.attest, which is [deprecated and now disabled](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/safetynet-api-clients/jbsEAqDABNM)

In order to get the Client, use:

```
SafetyNet.getClient(this).attest()
```

See [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetClient#attest(byte[],%20java.lang.String)) and [the example here](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation) for more details